# PHP MySQL Request Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, syntax-error

I have a query on my PHP code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE operasyonkayitlari SET tarihgun=FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-28800, "%Y.%m.%d"), tezgah='".$_REQUEST['tezgah']."', operatoradi='".$_REQUEST['operator']."', ayarepoch=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), durum='AYARDA' where isemri='".$_REQUEST['isemri']."' and operasyonno='".$_REQUEST['operasyonno']."'");
```

Look at this closely:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-28800, "%Y.%m.%d")
```

The characters with % symbol gives me this syntax error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in C:\wamp\www\ayarabasla.php on line 4
```

How did I write the query with % symbols?

Comment: i see this kind of 'errors' more and more on SOF, don't you guys do some debugging? Don't you have a editor with highlightning? And whats even more wired, the error is displayed but you can't see it?

Comment: I was using NotePad for writing this. I was looking a good PHP IDE. They said me phpStorm is good but it's too slow and not free for me. Do you advice some good PHP ide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax highlighter show your error. It's a quote issue. Escape your inner double quotes:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE operasyonkayitlari SET tarihgun=FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-28800, \"%Y.%m.%d\"), tezgah='".$_REQUEST['tezgah']."', operatoradi='".$_REQUEST['operator']."', ayarepoch=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), durum='AYARDA' where isemri='".$_REQUEST['isemri']."' and operasyonno='".$_REQUEST['operasyonno']."'");
```

You can use single quotes, too:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE operasyonkayitlari SET tarihgun=FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-28800, '%Y.%m.%d'), tezgah='".$_REQUEST['tezgah']."', operatoradi='".$_REQUEST['operator']."', ayarepoch=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), durum='AYARDA' where isemri='".$_REQUEST['isemri']."' and operasyonno='".$_REQUEST['operasyonno']."'");
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't see my quote error becouse I was using NotePad :) I think I should use some good IDE.